# htaccess is not redirecting me on index.php page or default page

Tags: php, .htaccess, redirect

When I try to go on *http://localhost/themobilesapp* then it still redirect me on *specification.php* page not redirecting me on *index.php*

Now, I'm going on my homepage by typing *http://localhost/themobilesapp/index.php*

This is my full htaccess code.

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews -Indexes

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

DirectoryIndex index.php

RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php

ErrorDocument 404 404error.php

RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z0-9-]+)?$ specification.php?url=$1 [L]

RewriteRule ^news/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)?$ news.php?url=$1 [L]

</IfModule>
```

How to re-direct it on index.php by typing *http://localhost/themobilesapp* ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't see the index.php in your htaccess

I think you mean something like:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php [L]
```

This would mean other redirects below this rewrite won't get executed. Order matters; Use L flags where required.

Your regex:

```
RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z0-9-]+)?$ specification.php?url=$1 [L]
```

Matches everything (even an empty string; as in your example). If you leave the last ? out; the other string won't be optional:

```
RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z0-9-]+)$ specification.php?url=$1 [L]
```

Comment: It is redirecting *http://localhost/themobilesapp* on index page. There are many pages links on homepage then it also redirect it on *index.php*

Comment: Then remove the `RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php [L]` line; and just keep the modified specification line.

Comment: I don't add anything. I only remove **?** from **RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z0-9-]+)$ specification.php?url=$1 [L]** then my code redirect **index.php**

Answer (score 1):

Try below rule like this,

```
DirectoryIndex index.php

RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php

ErrorDocument 404 404error.php

RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z0-9-]+)?$ specification.php?url=$1 [L]

RewriteRule ^news/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)?$ news.php?url=$1 [L]

RewriteRule ^$ /themobilesapp/index.php [R=301,L]
```

Comment: It doesn't work. When I type *http://localhost/themobilesapp* then it open this url *http://localhost/C:/wamp/www/theMobilesApp/index.php*
 and it show me error *FORBIDDEN You don't have permission to access /C:/wamp/www/theMobilesApp/index.php on this server.

*

Comment: Please try the new rule in answer.